# My graph doesn't display entirely x-axis and grid in the background (Matplotlib/Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some `revenues` against `EBIT` on a chart with a secondary Y-axis.
Everything seems to be ok except

- the grid doesn't display entirely.
- the x-axis doesn't display entirely either.

Does anyone have a solution to display entirely these 2 features ?

Here is a screen cap of my graph :

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoiE3.png)

Here is the data :

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWhMX.jpg)

And here is my code :

```
x = msft_ebit_revenue_new['period'] 
y1 = msft_ebit_revenue_new['EBIT']
y2 = msft_ebit_revenue_new['Revenues']
```

## Plot Line1 (Left Y Axis)

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(16,9), dpi= 80)
ax1.plot(x, y1, color='tab:red')
```

# Plot Line2 (Right Y Axis)

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2.plot(x, y2, color='tab:blue')
```

## Decorations

## ax1 (left Y axis)

```
ax1.set_xlabel('Period', fontsize=10)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0, labelsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('EBIT', color='tab:red', fontsize=20)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', rotation=0, labelcolor='tab:red' )
ax1.grid(alpha=.4)
```

## ax2 (right Y axis)

```
ax2.set_ylabel("Revenues ($ in millions)", color='tab:blue', fontsize=20)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:blue')
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(x), 60))
ax2.set_xticklabels(x[::60], rotation=90, fontdict={'fontsize':10})
ax2.set_title("EBIT vs Revenues (MSFT)", fontsize=22)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Thank you !

Alex

Comment: The issue seems to be with the following lines: ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(x), 60))
ax2.set_xticklabels(x[::60], rotation=90, fontdict={'fontsize':10}). On commenting these lines grid becomes visible.

Comment: Here, you are twinning x axis. ax2 = ax1.twinx(). Thus creating two y-axes. Hence, in my opinion, under these set of conditions, defining two different sets of grid lines and x axes leads to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

- Display x-axis labels
- Display grid

## Solution

Comment the following lines:

```
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(x), 60))
ax2.set_xticklabels(x[::60], rotation=90, fontdict={'fontsize':10})
```